# CD for google cloud functions using google cloud repository - how to automate deployment?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, gcloud, continuous-deployment, google-cloud-repository

I am new to GCP however did some read up of docs regarding deploying from google cloud repo https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/repo

however I stil miss some automation bit

to don't have call by myself the gcloud functions deploy locally rather delegate it to google cloud repo (smth similar to gitlab-ci does) to handle it after new changes pushed to certain branch.

The most desired scenario having something like .gitlab-ci yaml in my cloud functions repo which takes care of setup the cloud functions and linking it to certain dirs in repo.

Comment: will CLOSE soon probbably cause googled what I need I guess here https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/testing/test-cicd#functions-testing-cicd-python

Comment: Posted an answer, is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/testing/test-cicd#functions-testing-cicd-python) :

> Continuous Integration and Deployment (CI/CD) pipelines help to ensure
> that your functions work both locally and in a test environment on
> Google Cloud. Once you finish developing locally, you can configure a
> CI/CD platform such as Cloud Build to run your existing Cloud
> Functions tests on an ongoing basis. Continuous testing helps ensure
> that your code continues to work as intended and that your
> dependencies remain up-to-date. As Cloud Functions are not updated
> automatically, you can also configure CI/CD pipelines (including those
> built on top of Cloud Build) to automatically test and redeploy your
> functions from a source repository such as GitHub, Bitbucket, or Cloud
> Source Repositories.

You can also refer to the [Article](https://medium.com/@selsaber/ci-cd-for-gcp-serverless-cloud-functions-001-ae3ed055942c) and [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/setting-up-continuous-integration-on-cloud-function-c015a214c96e) for a brief description of the CI\CD for GCP Serverless Cloud Functions.
You can also refer to the [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68488770/15774176) which explains the brief aspect of CI/CD Pipeline for cloud functions and  how it works to resolve issue of re deployment as:

> The CICD uses Terraform inside Cloud Build ( cloud build yaml file
> contains `'terraform init' and terraform apply'`). Thus, push (or pull
> request) triggers a Cloud Build job, which executes Terraform.
>
> When the Terraform is triggered, the zip file is created in case the
> cloud function code has been modified. The SHA hash code of the zip
> file is different (if the code has been modified). Thus, the local
> variable with the GCS object name gets a different value. It means
> that the zip file is uploaded to the GCS bucket with the new name. As
> the source code object has now a new name `source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.cf_source_zip.name`, terraform finds out
> that the cloud function has to be redeployed (because the state file
> has the old name of the archive object). The cloud function is
> redeployed. On the other hand, if the code is not modified - the name
> `source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.cf_source_zip.name` is not modified, so
> Terraform does not deploy anything.