# How to trigger GCP Cloud Function V2 update when source GCS object changes IN-PLACE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-functions

I'm following the official [guide](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/terraform) on how to deploy GCP Cloud Function V2 with terraform.

Unfortunately it seems to have a bug - if I update my sources, the GCS object is updated but it does NOT trigger function update. I.e. the function never updates after the initial deployment.

After more digging, looks like it's an [old curse](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/1938), though unfortunately workarounds suggested do not work anymore:

- Changing labels or env vars doesn't trigger source reload
- Using `replace_triggered_by` causes function to be deleted first and created again, resulting in a downtime.

The only working [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68488277/how-can-i-deploy-google-cloud-functions-in-ci-cd-without-re-deploying-unchanged/68488770#68488770) I found is to embed zip file hash into the object name, which will trigger proper function update. The downside of this approach is that it doesn't keep history of the object versions (since it's a new object every time).

Does anyone have a working solution on how to *modify* GCP Cloud Function V2 w/o changing source object path on each iteration?

P.S. The `generation` property [looked](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/15405#issuecomment-1825707781) promising but unfortunately doesn't work as well.

Comment: Are you using Terraform `resource "google_storage_bucket` to load your code into GCS ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly as per the guide I mentioned: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/terraform

Comment: Does your bucket have `enabled = true` in its versioning block?

Comment: Yes. Confirmed it's set with gsutil.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest an alternative approach in which you don't manage function source code via Terraform.

As you are doing now, you might store the initial code for the function in a Cloud Storage object as a zip file. This code would be the minimal necessary code for the function to be deployed via Terraform. You can also add a lifecycle block to ignore future code changes.

From there on, you would update the function after uploading a new version of the code to the Cloud Storage bucket. It could be done in a CI/CD pipeline or as part of your current process.

This is a sample command to update the function after uploading the code to GCS:

```
gcloud functions deploy --source gs://my-bucket/my-object.zip
```

Comment: Well, there are many way to manage cloud functions but I was specifically asking about Terraform.

Comment: To be clear, I meant managing the function via Terraform, indeed, but relieving Terraform of the responsibility of detecting changes in its source code.